# Generating more data rows for a binary sparse matrix

Tags: distributions, dataset

I have a matrix that has 50 named rows and 15 named columns. Matrix contains 0 and 1 values and is 85% sparse. Similar to the 'last.fm dataset'. I would like to intelligently create more rows from my existing data. Was thinking of creating a model and fitting a 'multivariate binomial distribution', if that is even sensible. Any ideas or experience?

Comment: A *multivariate binomial distribution*  might well be sensible, but to make this answerable you need to tell us more context! What do you inten d your matrix to represent?  What is your real-life goal?

Comment: I would just like to 'upsample'. My recommender system is really unequiped to work with so small implicit datasets. Therefore I would like to generate more data, but would not like to copy paste the data, but make a more intelligent projection.